# How do I stop the ruff linter from moving imports into a TYPE CHECKING if block?

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, ruff

I have a pydantic basemodel that looks something like:

```
from pathlib import Path
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Model(BaseModel):
    log_file: Path
```

And my ruff pre-commit hook is re-ordering it to:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from pydantic import BaseModel

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from pathlib import Path


class Model(BaseModel):
    log_file: Path
```

Which is then causing the bug:

```
pydantic.errors.ConfigError: field "log_file" not yet prepared so type is still a ForwardRef, you might need to call Model.update_forward_refs()
```

Which I dont want to do. How can I stop ruff from re-ordering the imports like this? My `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file looks like:

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff-pre-commit
    rev: "v0.0.291"
    hooks:
      - id: ruff
        args: [--fix, --exit-non-zero-on-fix]
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 23.9.1
    hooks:
      - id: black
        language_version: python3
```

and my `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 120
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.eggs
  | \.git
  | \.hg
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | _build
  | buck-out
  | build
  | dist
  # The following are specific to Black, you probably don't want those.
  | blib2to3
  | tests/data
  | profiling
)/
'''


[tool.ruff]
line-length = 120
ignore = ["F405", "B008"]
select = ["E", "F", "B", "C4", "DTZ", "PTH", "TCH", "I001"]
# unfixable = ["C4", "B"]
exclude = ["docs/conf.py", "Deployment/make_deployment_bundle.py"]

[tool.ruff.per-file-ignores]
"**/__init__.py" = ["F401", "F403"]

[tool.ruff.isort]
split-on-trailing-comma = true
known-first-party = ["influxabart"]
no-lines-before = ["local-folder"]

section-order = ["future","standard-library","third-party","first-party","this","local-folder"]

[tool.ruff.isort.sections]
"this" = ["InfluxTools"]
```

Comment: What does your pre-commit hook look like? Just using `ruff` by itself it doesn't seem to make that sort of change (it will lint and reformat but I have never seen it actually change the logic of the code).

Comment: @larsks I added my `pyproject.toml` file to the question as well, I guess it also had `isort` (this is not my repo, but I have made some changes and the pre-commit hook is causing the break)

Comment: Where did you get that list of `select` options from?

Comment: @blueteeth I did not make this repo, they were already in the `pyproject.toml` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't reproduced this, but I think your list of `select` options is causing this. I know that this isn't the default behaviour of ruff.

```
select = ["E", "F", "B", "C4", "DTZ", "PTH", "TCH", "I001"]
```

Even though the [official readme](https://github.com/snok/flake8-type-checking#error-codes) says `TC*` is the code for flake8-type-checking, [this issue](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/2761) hints that `TCH*` is.

From the README:

```
TC001   Move application import into a type-checking block
TC002   Move third-party import into a type-checking block
TC003   Move built-in import into a type-checking block
```

So `TC003` is what's happening to you. Or `TCH003` is what I'm guessing ruff calls it.

So I think the solution is to remove that `"TCH"` field from the `select` in your `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: I think this also happens if `unsafe` fixes are applied with `ruff check`. Given the behaviour might be wanted more than it's not - is there a way to stop it happening for particular imports within particular files? In the context of OP's post - i might want `Path` actually imported in the module with pydantic, but everywhere else the movement to the TYPE CHECKING block might be fine.